# dataDrivenPages.pageRow is read-only or can be modified?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap, data-driven-pages

In ArcMap  [Help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/datadrivenpages-class.htm#P_GUID-7C69EFC8-9C4E-45FA-9482-997A8673E839)  it says **pageRow is read only**, but in explanation it says "The index layer fields **can then be read and/or modified** as necessary."

(I did not succeed to use it with setValue while getValue worked)

Comment: it looks like in future it may be possible to use it to write also - similarly to update cursor - see [comment from ESRI staff](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/260709/108284)

Answer (score 3):

Even though it is hard to guess your main purpose by accessing to the [row object](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/row.htm), the second example on the same help page shows a sample use. The main aim here is to read data from the respective row of the table (as row object) and manipulate it if necessary.

In the example of four-page-map, it changes the title if a column value of the respective row has required information,

e.g. this is where it access to the row object's TSR field value, which is populated either 080102 or 031400 (see the commented part below)

`fieldValue = mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageRow.TSR  #example values from a field called TSR are "080102", "031400"`

then extracts some information

`township, range, section = fieldValue[:2].strip("0"), fieldValue[2:-2].strip("0"), fieldValue[-2:].strip("0")`

and formats the title as to whether the section part has value, such as:

```
if section != "": 
    TRSTitle.text = "Section {0} T.{1}N. R.{2}W. W.M.".format(section, township, range)
else:
    TRSTitle.text = "T.{0}N. R.{1}W. W.M.".format(township, range)
```

In summary, you can read row -information, manipulate and use it somewhere else but cannot change the actual row object value , which is similar to [search cursor](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/searchcursor.htm) behaviour.

Comment: it looks like in future it may be possible to use it similarly to update cursor see [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/260709/108284) answer

Answer (score 0):

**Info from ESRI staff** on "*why does it says "pageRow (Read Only)" and at the same time "can then be read and/or modified*"**:**

"*This has gone un-noticed for a long time.  I tested this a variety of ways but it appears to be truly r/o.  I can not remember if it was r/w at one point and we forgot to flip the doc.

We will make a correction but it is already too late for the 10.6 release.

Jeff*"